# Mobilefirst 8.0 Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Android Cordova applications are able to receive and display, push notification while on click on notification application is not opening but notification gets cleared.

I am using Mobilefirst version 8.0. Following [Link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/) for push notification implementation.

What will be the issue?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the application or you see this with the sample as-is?

Comment: @VivinK I do not made any changes its just I am following given link. I am getting notifications even when application running I can see notification in javascript alert. But when app is in background that time on click of notification application is not opening thats the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml file of the generated project (in Android Studio after building the Cordova project):

```
<activity android:name="com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushNotificationHandler"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
```

Comment: @Idan When application is open notification is not coming same working when application in background. Is there any change have to make in manifest for this?

Comment: @IdanAdar there is no error. Same issue I am facing when download sample push app from IBM site. Application is not getting notification in tray when app is open.

Comment: It's not supposed to be in tray when open. There should be an alert.

Comment: @IdanAdar Yah thats I am asking if I want in tray then is there any change I can do to get that in tray?

Comment: That is not how push notification work. When the app is open the notification is displayed in the app, not in the tray.